# Need help in renaming file when uploading multiple instances

Tags: php, mysql, upload, renaming

I have this script for multiple image uploader and the problem is renaming the files. Well, I want to give names to the images like albumid_photoid.png (example 4_1.png). When selecting multiple images in the loop I always get same name (look at the last variable `$newName`) (exampl: 4_1.jpg, 4_1.jpg, 4_1.jpg, - supposing I've selected 3 files).

```
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
        $count_files = count($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']);
        $sql_album_id = "SELECT * FROM albums WHERE title = '".$_GET['album']."'";
        $res_album_id = mysql_query($sql_album_id) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_album_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_album_id);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $count_files; $i++) {
        // Access the $_FILES global variable for this specific file being uploaded
        // and create local PHP variables from the $_FILES array of information
        $fileName = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"][$i]; // The file name
        $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"][$i]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
        $fileType = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"][$i]; // The type of file it is

        $fileSize = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"][$i]; // File size in bytes
        $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["error"][$i]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
        $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName); // Split file name into an array using the dot
        $fileExt = end($kaboom); // Now target the last array element to get the file extension
        $fileTitle = $kaboom[0];

        // START PHP Image Upload Error Handling --------------------------------------------------
        if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
            echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.<br />";

        } else if($fileSize > 5242880) { // if file size is larger than 5 Megabytes
            echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than 5 Megabytes in size.<br />";
            unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder

        } else if (!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName) ) {
            // This condition is only if you wish to allow uploading of specific file types    
            echo "ERROR: Your image was not .gif, .jpg, or .png.<br />";
            unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder

        } else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1) { // if file upload error key is equal to 1
            echo "ERROR: An error occurred while processing the file. Try again.<br />";

        }
        // END PHP Image Upload Error Handling ---------------------------------

        $row_select = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_select);

        // renaming images
        $sql_count = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM photos WHERE album_id = '".$row_album_id['id']."'";
        $res_count = mysql_query($sql_count) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_count = mysql_fetch_row($res_count);
        $rc = $row_count[0] + 1;
        $fileTitle = $row_album_id['id']."_".$rc;
        $newName = $fileTitle.".".$fileExt;
        echo $newName;

    }

}
```

Comment: you really should check for `['error']` **BEFORE** you do anything else. Plus you are vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Your file extension regex is invalid and would let `foogif` through as a valid filename. You're fetching from $res_select, but never run a query to produce that handle, blah blah blah

Comment: @marc-b $res_select variable is in the rest of my code, and ['error'] has no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you only need to change:

```
$rc = $row_count[0] + 1;
```

to:

```
$rc = $i + 1;
```

as `$i` is the counter you are using for the images.

And just in case, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and you have an sql injection problem. You'd better switch to PDO or mysqli and use prepared statements with bound variables.

**Edit:** To be able to get the next sequence number from the database, you have to store the images in the database, otherwise you will never get an increase in the number of images found.

Apart from that this method will fail: If you delete for example the 2nd image of 8, your count will give you 8 as the next available number and you will overwrite your number 8 which is actually your 7th image.

You need to store the sequence numbers in the database to make sure you don't overwrite anything.

Comment: I got that but databases are the problem. I want to continue the sequence from database. For example if i have 8 pics with same album_id i want to name 3 next pics 9, 10 and 11. Get it?

Comment: @AmirRami Do you have the sequence number stored in the database and if yes, how / where?

Comment: No, i've got this:
$sql_count = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM photos WHERE album_id = '".$row_album_id['id']."'";
                        $res_count = mysql_query($sql_count) or die(mysql_error());
                        $row_count = mysql_fetch_row($res_count);

Comment: You're right. But dou you have any other idea of naming the images uniquely, but not id - auto increment

Comment: @AmirRami I would store them in the database together with a sequence number so that you can identify the file name easily. Then with a `SELECT MAX(sequence_number)` you can get the highest and using `foreach` loops it does not matter whether there are missing numbers when you display them.